# sshfs mounts from command line but not through fstab

Tags: network-share, ssh-keys, sshfs

I'm able to mount an sshfs network share from the command line (using Ubuntu 14.04), like this:

```
sshfs server-name:/usr/local/things /home/myname/stuff
```

but I can't make it persistent using fstab. Here's my

```
sshfs#server-name:/usr/local/things /home/myname/other-stuff fuse comment=sshfs,defaults,noauto,idmap=user,allow_other,reconnect,BatchMode=yes,_netdev 0 0
```

It's not a permissions problem, because - sometimes, at least - a "shared-things" directory is created in the mount directory, but it's empty. Inexplicably, other times, nothing at all is created...
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing `comment=sshfs,defaults,noauto,idmap=user,allow_other,reconnect,BatchMode=yes,_netdev` to just `defaults`, to see if it's an error in that line? Also, you could try using `sshfs#user@localhost:/usr/local/things /home/myname/stuff`

Comment: @Stretch, you seem to be correct: I stripped the arguments down to "defaults" and added one argument at a time. "fuse comment=sshfs,defaults,allow_other 0 0" has the share up and running. I'll experiment with the others later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Stretch has identified the correct methodology:  I stripped the arguments down to "defaults" and added one argument at a time. "fuse comment=sshfs,defaults,allow_other 0 0" has the share up and running. I'll experiment with the others later.